# Postgres - Move the records from one table to another based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with millions of rows in postgres. I wanted to move records from one table to another.

Table name - **event** 
List of columns:

```
"id"
"url"
"parent_id"
"created"
"created_by"
"last_modified"
"last_modified_by"
"tags"
"type"
"sub_type"
"category"
"name"
"preference"
```

Table name - **preference** 
List of columns:

```
"id" - If the entity_type is event, id column in the event table goes here
"entity_type" // event or slot.
"preference"
"created"
"created_by"
"last_modified"
"last_modified_by"
"parent_entity_id"
```

And these tables are already populated with millions of data. And I have added a new column named `preference` in the event table, which does not have any data.
Now, I wanted to move the

```
preference table preference column data to the event table preference column.
```

**Condition:** 
Migrating the data from the preference column (In preference table) to the preference column (In event table) only when the entity_type is an event. And the insert should
happen with the corresponding row in the event table.

I tried this query, but this seems to be incorrect. And Postgres throws a syntax error.

```
insert into <schema_name>.event a (preference) where a.id = '<eventId goes here>' (select preference from <schema_name>.preference where entity_id = '<eventId goes here>'
and entity_type = 'event')
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `update` instead of `insert`, because the table is already populated with data.

```
update event e
set preference = (select preference from preference p where p.entity_id = e.id and entity_type = 'event')
```

Comment: Since the preference and event table has millions of data, updating the query each and every time is a tedious task. Is there any way to use functions and iterate it over the loop?

Comment: @Aishu you can simply curate the `where` clause to update all rows at once, that would be most efficient

Comment: In order to use the where clause, I need to first figure out the list of id's in the event table. If I use an update query like this, I need to manually modify event id in the update query each and every time, because event table has millions of rows. So I was thinking of using loop so that for each iteration the update would happen accordingly in the event table. If you agree can you help me with this

Comment: @Aishu then I would go with CTE where I would keep all the ids